# Typescript generic conditional-partial property without type assertion

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a type that has an optional property depending on the generic parameter passed. Something like:

```
type PartialWhen<Bool, T> = Bool extends true ? Partial<T> : T
type PartialWhenExtends<Base, Parent, T> = PartialWhen<Base extends Parent ? true : false, T>

type Props<V> = {
  value: V
} & PartialWhenExtends<V, string, {
  getValue: (item: V) => string
}>

function getPropsValue<V>({ value, getValue }: Props<V>): string {
  if (getValue !== undefined) {
    return getValue(value)
  }

  return value
}

const props1: Props<string> = {
  value: '123'
}
console.log(getPropsValue(props1))

const props2: Props<number> = {
  value: 123,
  getValue: (val) => val.toString()
}
console.log(getPropsValue(props2))

const props3: Props<string> = {
  value: 'abc',
  getValue: (val) => val.concat(val)
}
console.log(getPropsValue(props3))
```

In the example above, I want the `getValue` to be required when `V` is not `string`. When calling `getPropsValue`, the typehint works correctly. The problem is in the `return value` of `getPropsValue` in which I got `Type 'V' is not assignable to type 'string'`, even though it is required when `V` is not `string` and would have returned in the condition above it.

The only solution I am able to use to solve this is by asserting the `value` as `string`.
I also tried changing the partial types definition multiple times & using union types, but unfortunately the result is the same.
Another solution that I tried is to check if the `value` is type of `string`, if not, just returns an empty string. While this works in this case, it is not possible where the return value is a generic.
I will use the `PartialWhenExtends` quite a lot, and would prefer to not do assertion everywhere.
Is there a way I can write the partial types so Typescript can correctly infer the type? If not, is there any other solution that can fit into this kind of use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Fix your code to be correct for `Props<string | number>` case
2. Make your code explicitly check for a string

```
type PartialWhen<Bool, T> = Bool extends true ? Partial<T> : T
type PartialWhenExtends<Base, Parent, T> = Base extends Parent ? Partial<T> : T

type Props<V> =
    { value: V } &
    PartialWhenExtends<[V], [string], { getValue: (item: V) => string }>
    
function getPropsValue<V>({ value, getValue }: Props<V>): string {
    if (getValue !== undefined) {
        return getValue(value)
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string')
        return value
    throw new Error()
}
// ok
getPropsValue<string>({ value: 'asd' })
// ^?
getPropsValue<'asd'>({ value: 'asd' })
// ^?
getPropsValue<string & { a: 1 }>({ value: 'asd' as any })
// ^?

// errors
getPropsValue<string | number>({ value: 123 })
// ^?
getPropsValue<number>({ value: 123 })
// ^?
```

---

Your function can be called as

```
getPropsValue<string | number>({} as any)
// ^? 
function getPropsValue<string | number>({ value, getValue }: {
    value: string | number;
} & ({
    getValue: (item: string | number) => string;
} | Partial<{
    getValue: (item: string | number) => string;
}>)): string
```

so TS is correct about your code being wrong.

I've got the code working without assertion as

```
function getPropsValue<V>(
    data: V extends string
        ? { value: V, getValue?: undefined } | { value: V, getValue: (item: V) => string }
        : { value: V, getValue: (item: V) => string }
): string
getPropsValue<number | string>({} as any)
// ^?
// function getPropsValue<string | number>(data: {
//     value: string;
//     getValue?: undefined;
// } | {
//     value: string;
//     getValue: (item: string) => string;
// } | {
//     value: number;
//     getValue: (item: number) => string;
// }): string
```

but at the moment it loses non-split `{ value: V, getValue?: undefined }` it stops working.

Comment: Hi! The `string | number` case should be fine as TS will complain that `getValue` is missing. The `string & { a: 1 }` and `asd` cases should be fine as well since they are both can be treated as a `string` when returned. For the `getPropsValue` function, I tried your overload, but it still requires me to explicitly check if `value` is `string`, so I take it that it is impossible to do this without an explicit check, right?

Comment: After looking for a while, I didn't find any ways that doesn't involve type assertions or explicit checks, so I will accept your answer. Thanks!